# How much does it cost to change Tor identity?

Tags: circuit

Assume we are refreshing a web page very quickly and fresh identity is needed for each request. My question is how often we can change IP on Tor network?

More briefly how much computation and how much time (in average please) is required for each new identity?

Comment: Why would you need a new path for every request?

Answer (score 8):

Setting up circuits is very expensive.  It involves several round trips, and it involves lots of public/private key operations for the servers.

Continually creating new circuits at a high frequency is wasteful and thus quite abusive.  Please don't do it.