# How often should i click on "Create new identity"?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, identity-change

I know that this is to clear cache, cookies, DNS and also other things that i don't know.

I want to know when should i "Create new identity".

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your privacy needs. Tor does this on it's own to an extent every ten minutes (at least with your exit node)

For instance, if you wanted to visit a site repeatedly as a new user, you should do it every refresh. For normal users, the default is fine. It all depends on what you feel you need. To completely start anew, every so often restarting tor browser is best

Comment: Tor changes exit node (IP address) every ten minutes, but it does not create a new identity automatically. Prior cookies remain. Best to quit and restart, or select New Identity on the interval you are most comfortable with based on your threat model.

Comment: @pseudon I've updated my answer with some of your info

Comment: Please see also this answer: https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/989/88

Comment: @JensKubieziel no applicable answers there